# Trace instructions in QEMU Full System Emulation (RISC-V)

Tags: linux, trace, qemu, riscv, instructions

As a college homework I have to run a benchmark on a system that uses RISC-V architecture.

Note: I don't have much knowledge of Linux and I don't know almost anything about QEMU.

**About the virtual machine with RISC-V architecture:**

To access a system with RISC-V architecture I used QEMU and as I'm using WSL2 to access a Linux kernel I used the tutorial below to install QEMU inside WSL2 and build the risc-v system with debian:

[Emulating RISC-V Debian on WSL2 | David Burela’s blog](https://blog.davidburela.com/2020/11/15/emulating-risc-v-debian-on-wsl2/)

I was able to install it correctly and run the QEMU virtual machine with RISC-V architecture.

**About the benchmark:**

As a benchmark I'm using JPEG2000 from MediaBench II which you can access at this link:
[MediaBench II (slu.edu)](https://cs.slu.edu/%7Efritts/mediabench/)

The benchmark consists of running the JPEG2000 encoder using the provided application called “Jasper” with the benchmark image included in the files. Thus, the application takes the image file “input_base_4CIF.ppm” which is in the ppm format and encodes it to the jp2 format (JPEG2000) generating the output file “output_base_4CIF_96bps.jp2”.

To run the benchmark:

1. I accessed the RISC-V virtual machine through QEMU (which runs Debian)
2. Inside the virtual machine, I downloaded all the source code, data, & scripts for JPEG-2000 using wget
3. I compiled all scripts of the JPEG2000 algorithm as well as the Jasper application scripts following the included guides (as I compiled inside the virtual machine, I guarantee that the files were compiled for the RISC-V architecture)
4. I entered the jpg2000enc folder with the command:

   $ cd jpg2000enc
5. I deleted the jpg2000 image already included in the output_base folder with the commands:

   $ cd output_base
   $ rm output_base_4CIF_96bps.jp2
6. I went back to the jpg2000enc folder with the command

   $ cd ..
7. Finally I ran the command that runs Jasper for the image provided (input_base_4CIF.ppm) which is in the input_base folder with the command:

   $ jasper -f ./input_base/input_base_4CIF.ppm -F ./output_base/output_base_4CIF_96bps.jp2 -T jp2 -O rate=0.010416667
8. I accessed the output_base folder to check if the jpg2000 file was generated successfully

   $ cd output_base
   $ ls
9. I saw that the file was generated successfully!

Note that everything ran perfectly!

**Now the problem I'm failing to solve:**

For the next steps of my homework, I need to log all the RISC-V instructions executed when I run the command:
$ jasper -f ./input_base/input_base_4CIF.ppm -F ./output_base/output_base_4CIF_96bps.jp2 -T jp2 -O rate=0.010416667

**How can I trace all RISC-V instructions as they are translated by QEMU during execution of the presented command?**

*Ps: It's important to mention that I don't want to trace the x86 instructions that are actually executed by my processor when QEMU translates the RISC-V instructions of the jasper application, I really need the RISC-V instructions.*

Comment: You can use gdb to exec and debug file and see all instructions that were used while executed. If your debian have no gdb, clone it and build. Use target help while gdb is running.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.